# How to properly handle database connections?

Tags: python, database

I would like to optimize my system, to be able to handle large amount of users down the road. Even if website never gets to be popular, I want to do things right.

Anyway, I am currently using a combo of 2 database solutions:

```
1.) Either SQL (mysql, postgre) via SQLAlchemy OR MongoDB
2.) Redis
```

I use Redis as 'hot' database (as its much much faster and unloads stress on primary database solution), and than sync data between two via cron tasks. I use Redis for session management, statistics etc. However, if my Redis server would crash, site would remain operational (fallback to sql/mongo).

So this is my design for data. Now I would like to do proper connecting.

As both sql/mongo and redis are required on 99% of pages, my current design is the following:

```
- When new HTTP request comes in, I connect to all databases
- When page finishes rendering, I disconnect from databases
```

Now obviously I am doing a lot of connecting/disconnecting. I've calculated that this model could sustain a decent amount of visitors, however I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Would persisting connections between requests improve performance/load or would the sheer amount of open connections clog the server?
Would you recommend creating a connection pool? If so, when should the connection pool be created and how should the Model access it (or fetch connection objects from it).

I am sorry if these questions are stupid, but I am a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is a good way to optimize things beforehand. You don't know where bottlenecks will apear and you are probably just wasting time for things you won't need in future mostly.

Database type can be changed later if you will use ORM, so right now you can use any. Anyway if your site popularity will raise high, you will need to get more servers, add some task queues (celery) etc. There is ton of things you can do later to optimize. Right now you should just focus on making your site popular and use technologies that can scale in future.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to leave connections open, you should definitely consider pooling to avoid crudding up the system with per-session connections or something of the like (as long as they are locked properly to avoid leaking). That said, the necessity of doing this isn't clear. If you can quantify the system with some average/worst-case connection times to the databases, you'd be able to make a much more informed decision.

Try running a script(s) to hammer your system and investigate DB related timing. This should help you make an immediate decision about whether to keep persistent connections and a handy DB load script for later on.